# How to filter and remove dict elements based on a value threshold?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have several dictionaries in a list with this structure:

```
[{'store': 'walmart',
  'store_id': 0,
  'store_info': {'grapes': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 1}},
   'tomatoes': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 6}},
   'oranges': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
   'bottled water': {'availability': {'No': 10, 'Yes': 5}},
   "india's mangos": {'availability': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}},
   'water melon': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
   'lemons': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 3}},
   'kiwifruit': {'availability': {'No': 4, 'Yes': 2}},
   'pineapple': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 20}},
   'total_yes': 23,
   'total_no': 23,
   'total': 46,
   'id': [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]}},
{'store': 'Costco',
  'store_id': 24,
  'store_info': {'papaya': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 1}},
   'lychee': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 1}},
   'fig': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
   'blackberry': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}},
   "india's mangos": {'availability': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}},
   'plum': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 2}},
   'total_yes': 43,
   'total_no': 3,
   'total': 46,
   'id': [3, 4, 36, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2]}}  
]
```

How can I filter all the Yes and No values which are greater or equal to 5 at the same time? For example, given the above dict. The expected output should look like this if the dictionary fullfil the condition:

```
[
{'store': 'walmart',
  'store_id': 0,
  'store_info': {
  'tomatoes': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 6}},
  'bottled water': {'availability': {'No': 10, 'Yes': 5}},
  'pineapple': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 20}},
  'total_yes': 23,
  'total_no': 23,
  'total': 46,
  'id': [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]}
  }
]
```

In the above example, `'india's mangos': {'availability': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}}` should be filtered or removed. Because, although the 5 fullfil Yes treshold, the key No, doesnt fulfill the treshold at the same time. Alternatively, `'pineapple': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 20}}`, should remain in the  dict, because `Yes` key has as values 20, which is greater than the 5 threshold. Finally, the second dict (costco) should be removed because none of its keys are at leas 5.

So far I tried to iterate over the structure, however, I am making too many loops, is there a more compact way of getting the expected output?:

```
a_lis = []
for e in list_dict:
    try:
        l = list(e['store_info'].keys())
        for i in l:
            #print(e['store_info'][i]['availability'])
            if e['store_info'][i]['availability']['No']>=5 and e['availability'][i]['availability']['Yes']>= 5:
                a_lis.append(e['store_info'][i]['availability'])
                print(a_lis)
            else:
                pass
    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "You are making too many loops"? If it works, there's nothing wrong with having nested for-loops. Even if we did come up with a more compact way to do it, it would still be a nested for-loop.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 It is complicating the task because I will need to recreate the dictionary.

Comment: My guess is that you want a recursive solution.

Comment: @JDo So basically, you want a way to do what you put above, except changing the original list instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I need to be apendding and updating components from the dict. @M-Chen-3 or if there's another way of doing it it would be helpful to know.

Comment: @JDo Okay, thank you for clarifying your question.

Comment: My second guess is that modifying the original list of dicts (in place, as you iterate through it) is going to create more problems than it solves

Comment: @PaulH Why recursion could solve this?

Comment: It's only guess since you implied you wanted to avoid loops and you have a nested data structure/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach:

```
# where data is the input
filtered = []

for store in data:
    avail_dict = {}
    extra_dict = {}
    for item, value in store['store_info'].items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            okay = value['availability'].get('No',0) >= 5 and value['availability'].get('Yes',0) >= 5
            if okay:
                avail_dict[item] = value
        else:
            extra_dict[item] = value
    if avail_dict:
        avail_dict.update(extra_dict)
        new_store = dict(store)
        new_store['store_info'] = avail_dict
        filtered.append(new_store)
```

Result for `filtered` (input `data` is unchanged):

```
[{'store': 'walmart',
  'store_id': 0,
  'store_info': {'tomatoes': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 6}},
   'bottled water': {'availability': {'No': 10, 'Yes': 5}},
   'pineapple': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 20}},
   'total_yes': 23,
   'total_no': 23,
   'total': 46,
   'id': [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]}}]
```

Comment: I am getting a KeyError: 'Yes'. It seems that some elements do not have the 'Yes' key. How can I filter those examples, for being incomplete?

Comment: I added try except, does that generalize for this case?

Comment: I guess you could fetch the `dict` values by using `get` instead, and returning `0` if nothing is found?  So like `value['availability'].get('Yes', 0) >= 5`. This would make sense if an absence of Yes or No means there were no responses for that value

Comment: Could you update the solution for completeness? I added thet try/except Key error. However, your reasoning is better.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

That's not difficult.I would recommend you create a new list.(And revise the dictionary directly.)

```py
lst = [{'store': 'walmart',
        'store_id': 0,
        'store_info': {'grapes': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 1}},
                       'tomatoes': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 6}},
                       'oranges': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
                       'bottled water': {'availability': {'No': 10, 'Yes': 5}},
                       'india\'s mangos': {'availability': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}},
                       'water melon': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
                       'lemons': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 3}},
                       'kiwifruit': {'availability': {'No': 4, 'Yes': 2}},
                       'pineapple': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 20}},
                       'total_yes': 23,
                       'total_no': 23,
                       'total': 46,
                       'id': [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]}},
       {'store': 'Costco',
        'store_id': 24,
        'store_info': {
            'papaya': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 1}},
                       'lychee': {'availability': {'No': 5, 'Yes': 1}},
                       'fig': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 2}},
                       'blackberry': {'availability': {'No': 2, 'Yes': 5}},
                       'india\'s mangos': {'availability': {'No': 3, 'Yes': 5}},
                       'plum': {'availability': {'No': 1, 'Yes': 2}},
                       'total_yes': 43,
                       'total_no': 3,
                       'total': 46,
                       'id': [3, 4, 36, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2]}}
       ]

result_list = []
for sub_dict in lst:
    if sub_dict['store_info']['total_yes'] >= 5 and sub_dict['store_info']['total_no'] >= 5:
        result_list.append(sub_dict)
        key_need_to_be_removed = [k for k, v in sub_dict['store_info'].items() if type(v) is dict and (v['availability']['Yes'] < 5 or v['availability']['No'] < 5)]
        for k in key_need_to_be_removed: # remove the dict under dictionary['store_info']
            del sub_dict['store_info'][k]

print(result_list)
```

Result:

```
[{
    'store': 'walmart',
    'store_id': 0,
    'store_info': {
        'tomatoes': {
            'availability': {
                'No': 5,
                'Yes': 6
            }
        },
        'bottled water': {
            'availability': {
                'No': 10,
                'Yes': 5
            }
        },
        'pineapple': {
            'availability': {
                'No': 5,
                'Yes': 20
            }
        },
        'total_yes': 23,
        'total_no': 23,
        'total': 46,
        'id': [3, 4, 6, 2, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]
    }
}]
```